# Where is the Elasticsearch scripts directory?

Tags: elasticsearch

The Elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) say this:

> Save the contents of the script as a file called config/scripts
>   /my_script.groovy on every data node in the cluster

I was wondering where to find the `config/scripts` directory

Answer (score 1):

The `config/scripts` directory most likely needs to be created. To make sure Elasticsearch picks up your script, you should create the `scripts` directory inside the folder which contains your elasticsearch.yml configuration file.
This is often something like `/etc/elasticsearch` on Linux. Otherwise, just do a search for `elasticsearch.yml` on your machine and note the folder it's in.